# Android equivalent to iOS Simulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

The iOS simulator is great for testing websites locally on various Apple devices. Is there an Android equivalent?

I've tried Android studio, but I seem to have to build a device every time (unless I'm doing it wrong). I'm mainly concerned in seeing the sites in the default Chrome browser (Version 53, 59 etc).

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to test? An app or a website? If you have to "build a device" every time, you are doing it wrong.

The device emulator that you are using in android studio is the intended way to run android without a physical device. Ensure you have properly installed haxm if you are finding the emulator unbearably slow. It may help.

If you really want to try something else, you could try using the genymotion emulator. It is quite comparable to the official one though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I find the Android Emulator slow on Crossbrowsertesting.com. The browser in the Android Studio is fine, its just I have to build a virtual device everytime. Unlike iOS sim where you just select the version you require.

Comment: Ah in that case, sorry but your question is off topic for this site. Try talking to their support? I have no experience with their product.

Comment: Im not after support for crossbrowsertesting. I want a local Android simulator

Comment: I've amended the question to remove reference to crossbrowsertesting.com